# How to activate iPhone12 and import original phone data?

Tags: iphone

My original phone is iPhone7 and the new phone is iPhone12, how do I import the original phone data into the new phone?

Comment: How far did you get? It pretty much tells you as you go how to set it up - https://support.apple.com/HT202033

Answer (score 2):

Use Quick Start to transfer data to a new iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210216

Use iTunes or the Finder to transfer data from your previous iOS device to your new iPhone.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210218

Restore your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch from a iCloud backup

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977